# vba intercept internet explorer link click

Tags: javascript, vba, internet-explorer, excel, automation

I'm using excel 2010, vba. I have a web page at work - which I created, and when the user clicks on a link, i want to intercept that link, and run vba (not the javascript onclick event).   ie bind the onclick event to VBA function or sub if possible. Some sites hint it can be done. Question for an automation guru. Note i do not want to click the link thru automation (the below code does this) I want the user to click and the VBA intercept the click ( note, i don't want to replace the javascript with more js I want to call VBA). I'm using the InternetExplorer object but might need to use another ie object or library reference as you advise.

The below code (example) opens the www's first web page and clicks on the link. I want to intercept this click and run vb code.

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
sURL = "http://info.cern.ch/hypertext/WWW/TheProject.html" ' www's first web page

ie.Navigate sURL
ie.Visible = True
Do While ie.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop
Set oForm = ie.Document.getElementsByName("0") ' worlds first ever anchor/ hyper link
Set oLink = oForm.Item(0)

'oLink.onclick = ' set/add to VBA function to replace/set javascript onlclick event ie. to intercept click

oForm.Item(0).Click ' run vba code to display msgbox "hello World" not navigate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a class module and `WithEvents` to hook up VBA-hosted events which can be triggered from IE. This code is for links, but most other events can also be captured.

EDIT: added mouseover/out for good measure...

**Regular module**

```
Private lnks As Collection 'of clsLink

Sub Tester()

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer, el, sURL
    Dim lnk As clsLink

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    sURL = "http://info.cern.ch/hypertext/WWW/TheProject.html" 

    ie.Navigate sURL
    ie.Visible = True
    Do While ie.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set lnks = New Collection

    For Each el In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
        Set lnk = New clsLink
        lnk.Init el
        lnks.Add lnk
    Next

End Sub
```

**clsLink (class module)**

```
Option Explicit

'note "WithEvents" declaration
Private WithEvents lnk As MSHTML.HTMLAnchorElement

Private Function lnk_onclick() As Boolean
    Debug.Print "Link: '" & lnk.innerText & "' clicked!"
    lnk_onclick = False 'cancels navigation
    'lnk_onclick = True 'doesn't cancel navigation
End Function

Private Sub lnk_onmouseout()
    With lnk.Style
        .Color = "#00F"
        .backgroundColor = "#FFF"
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub lnk_onmouseover()
    With lnk.Style
        .Color = "#F00"
        .backgroundColor = "#0F0"
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub Init(el)
    Set lnk = el
End Sub
```

Add project references to:

- Microsoft Internet Controls
- Microsoft HTML Object Library

Comment: Thanks Tim..Works as advertised! WOW you are a guru! You can teach an old dog new tricks after all - i'm not talking about VBA :) but that does apply.  ! Hey like the hyper link colors thanks!

Comment: Thanks works well - the only trap the lnks collection , must be global, ie persist , as you have shown - just a note for others as i got caught up on this.