# KeyDown in WebBrowser (Excel VBA)

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

Is there a way to know what key is pressed if a WebBrowser is used in a UserForm?

Thanks in advance :)

Edit: I basically want to open a different UserForm on KeyDown, but the WebBrowser prevents that. Maybe I can run a Sub of my UserForm from the WebBrowser.

Comment: https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?398817-How-to-dedect-if-mouse-is-pressed-on-Webbrowser   More details about exactly what you're doing might be useful here.

Comment: ...assuming you mean what key was pressed while the web browser control has focus.

Comment: Thanks, though I think that's VB but I need VBA.

Comment: Well, it's a Canvas inside of a WebBrowser on a UserForm. Maybe it's possible to change focus everytime I don't acutally draw on the Canvas but I don't know how that should work.

Comment: No that kind of event capture works fine in VBA.  Do you control the loaded page?  There are a couple of ways to pass messages between the page and the hosting form object.  Similar previous questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599039/vba-intercept-internet-explorer-link-click/28599620#28599620 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388391/detect-event-on-ie-from-visio/7410092#7410092 for example

Comment: Thank you :) I have never done something like that in Excel, but thank you for the links, that gives me some hope. What do mean by "control"?

Comment: "control" - you wrote or host the page loaded into the web browser.

Comment: I just wrote the html/javascript code into a label on the worksheet and then I use document.write and refresh to load it. I saw it in a Youtube video (https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=71IbXHfunF8)

Comment: It's not just copy and paste, but I always try to understand the code and then maybe use it in future projects.

Comment: But you can paste that same code into your post here...   BTW a cell can hold 32k characters, so you could just paste your code in a cell.

Comment: I need the cells for something else (a lot of data) but thanks for the tip. I don't know if the html code is helpful, because it's just a canvas and some javascript to draw on it.

Comment: I guess I need more time to understand the links that you have posted but from what I understand it will help me a lot, once I understand it. I guess all I need is to put the keydown in my javascript and then somehow start a macro in my Excel project.

Comment: If you use your js to capture events then you can pass messages to your VBA (eg) by changing the value of a hidden input element on which you've hooked the change event in the VBA side.

Comment: Like Textbox_Change ?

Comment: Like in the second of the two links I posted above.

Comment: Okay, sorry. You mean the "Dim objHTML As clsHTML" code. You wrote "capturing the 'change' event on a textbox", which means that the textbox is in HTML, right? And how does it know that the HTML is in a WebBrowser? Sorry, it's hard for me to understand. I also found this link (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e0f4949e-0bf9-4c61-a43c-a7f30ce3319e/how-do-i-call-a-vba-macro-from-a-webbrowser-control?forum=isvvba).

Comment: Yes in your web page you can use (eg) `<input type="hidden" id="txtMsg">` then get a reference to that element from your hosting VBA userform: using a class to capture the input's events lets you respond to changes in the input's `value` in your VBA.  Your js sets the input's value, and that triggers your VBA event handler, which can read the value and take the appropriate action.

Comment: Okay, so I create a hidden input form in HTML and change it with "document.addEventListener('keydown', function);". Then I create a class in VBA and add the "Dim objHTML As clsHTML" code to it? Sorry if that is wrong 

Comment: I will look at creating an example but it's late here so maybe tomorrow.

Comment: No hurry, you already helped me so much. I didn't even know that something like a "VBA event handler, which can read the value" from HTML exists. You actually helped me understand what I am actually looking for, even though I am still struggling with understanding the code. Thank you. I thought changing the focus could somehow help but triggering VBA code via HTML/Javascript is a much better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK here's a very basic example to show you can send a message to the HTML page from VBA, and send a message in the other direction:

UserForm:

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim obj As webEvents 'must be Global to remain in scope...

'send a message to the browser page
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    'would need to escape the text sent if it contains (eg) '
    Me.WebBrowser1.Document.parentWindow.execScript "MessageIn('" & Me.TextBox1.Text & "')"
End Sub

'receive a message from the browser page
Public Sub HandleBrowserMessage(s As String)
    MsgBox "From web:" & vbLf & s
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate "about:blank"  'load a blank document
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    With Me.WebBrowser1.Document 'load some HTML
        .Open "text/html"
        .write Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
        .Close
    End With
    
    Set obj = New webEvents                  'new class instance
    Set obj.ParentForm = Me                  'for the callback
    Set obj.HtmlOutput = Me.WebBrowser1.Document.getElementById("msgOut")
End Sub
```

Class module `webEvents`:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public ParentForm As Object 'not As userform!
Public WithEvents HtmlOutput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement

'handling click since change seems unreliable
Private Function HtmlOutput_onclick() As Boolean
    ParentForm.HandleBrowserMessage CStr(HtmlOutput.Value)
End Function
```

HTML in Cell A1:

```html
<html><body>
<input type="hidden" id="msgOut" /><br>
To VBA: <input type="text" size="20" id="msg" />
<button  onclick="MessageOut()">Send to VBA</button><br><br>
From VBA: <span id="showMessage" style="color:#F00"></span><br>
<script>
function MessageIn(s){  document.getElementById("showMessage").innerText = s;  }
function MessageOut(s){  
    var el = document.getElementById("msgOut");
    el.value = document.getElementById("msg").value; 
    el.click();
}
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Thank you, for writing that code, that's really nice of you, taking your time for a stranger. I guess I need to learn everything about "WithEvents" if I want to understand the code. This link will help me (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/create-application-level-event-handler). I guess I need to activate the "Microsoft HTML Object Library" because otherwise "HTMLInputElement" doesn't show up when I write "Public WithEvents". I will upvote your answer as soon as I test it in Excel. Thank you.